# CollectionProxy. How to use it properly or how to solve my task in other way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have favorite user categories with causes. How can I get all causes from current_user.subscriptions ? Now I have code:

```
@categories = current_user.subscriptions
@causes = @categories.causes
```

but it returns

`undefined method 'causes' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Category:0x0000000375d700>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple solution:

```
@categories = current_user.subscriptions
@causes = Cause.where(category_id: @categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query instead

```
@categories = current_user.includes(:subscriptions => :causes)
```

It includes every category and causes related to current_user

Comment: full version of 2nd line was: `@causes = @categories.causes.includes([:user])` . So how to do nested include then ?

Comment: and my user object don't have include method !

Comment: includes is used for inner join, go through this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html